# reproducir/detener un archivo de audio en javascript con una pulsación de letra

Tags: javascript, keypressevent

Os comento, pretendo que el archivo se reproduzca y se detenga conforme sea pulsada una tecla en concreto.

He pensado también que se detenga con la pulsación de otra tecla, pero ahora estoy trabajando solo en una pulsación de una tecla, ne concreto la M (77).

Otro problema que tengo es que cada vez que pulso la música se reproduce el archivo tantas veces como la pulso, eso aún lo estoy resolviendo.

Os muestro el código:

```
    <script>
        window.onload=function () {
             document.onkeydown=teclado
        }

          //arranca la música en bucle
          function startAudio(reproducir){
            var musica =new Audio("musica.wav");
            musica.addEventListener('ended',function()
            {
                this.currentTime=0.60;
                this.play();
            },false);

            musica.play(); 
          }

 function teclado(objeto){
    var tecla = objeto.which;
    var num;
    var reproducir;

    //var situacionY = document.getElementById("mira").offsetLeft;
   // var situacionX = document.getElementById("mira").offsetTop;
    switch (tecla){            

        case 77://m
        reproducir=true;
        if(reproducir){
        startAudio();
            }
        break;
        case 78://n
        reproducir=false;

        stopAudio();

        break;
        default :alert("Q:esquivar. space:disparar cursor:moverse");
    }

}
</script>
```

Como veis empleo un `switch`, realmente el código tiene muchas cosas más, solo he eliminado lo que sobra para mostraros lo que no estoy resolviendo eficientemente; otros temas como el esquivar, el disparo, etc. ya los he resuelto o estoy mejorándolo, pero el problema concreto es este, solo este punto.

Comment: Estás creando un nuevo Audio cada vez, en lugar de pausar y reiniciar el ya existente

Comment: También, `reproducir` es una variable local dentro de`teclado`, nunca se inicializa, por lo tanto cada vez que se ejecuta `teclado`, `reproducir` comienza como `undefined`. Debes mover la declaración de `reproducir` fuera de la función `teclado` para que sea persistente. ¿Cómo funciona `stopAudio`? Saber eso ayudaría a formar una buena respuesta.

Comment: La idea era comenzar o reproducir la reproducción con una variable booleana que, según fuera true o false, activaba o detenía la reproducción.

Comment: stop audio está porque antes intenté atacar el problema poniendo el audio en una etiqueta de audio con dos botones pequeños de play y pausa visibles en pantalla y pequeños, pero no quería que se activaran con ratón, sino con las pulsaciones m y n.

Ví que no llegaba a ninguna parte y lo dejé en ese case mientras miraba otra solución, stop audio ni siquiera está implementada en este caso porque la eliminé, se quedó así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenías la idea correcta, yo haría algo como esto.

```
let reproducir = false;
let musica = new Audio("musica.wav");

//arranca la música en bucle
musica.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime=0.60;
    this.play();
}, false);
musica.play();

function resumeAudio () {
  if (!reproducir) {
    reproducir = true;
    musica.play();
  }
}

function pauseAudio () {
  if (reproducir) {
    reproducir = false;
    musica.pause();
  }
}

function teclado(objeto) {
  var tecla = objeto.which;
  var num;

  switch (tecla) {
      case 77: //m
        resumeAudio();
        break;
      case 78: //n
        pauseAudio();
        break;
      default:
        alert("Q:esquivar. space:disparar cursor:moverse");
  }

}

document.addEventListener('keydown', teclado, false);
```

Si no necesitas absolutamente iniciar el bucle en `0.60`, y puede comenzar desde el principio, puedes usar la propiedad [`.loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loop) en lugar usar el `ended` evento.

```
//arranca la música en bucle
musica.loop = true;
musica.play();
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien, solo que hay que eliminar una línea para que no de ningún problema aquí.  musica.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime=0.60;
    this.play();
}, false);
musica.play();  <= el musica.play() puede eliminarse